# How to create multiple row with two columns in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Well, in my react app, I want multiple rows having two columns. Just like first pink picture below.

[image]

But I am getting it like this. The divs are floating on the left side only, and nothing is working.

[image]

I think there should be a solution for using in map method.  react component code.

```
{dog.map((data) => (
      <div key={data.id} className="dogs-list">
        <div id={data.id} className="first-column">
          <img src={dogPic} alt="dog"></img>
          <h3>Dog's Name</h3>
          <h3>{data.name}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
        ))}
```

Nothing is working. Can anyone please help?

this is the styling of this area.

```
.page .dogs-list {
    /* display: flex; */
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .page .dogs-list .first-column {
    width: 50%;
    /* border: 2px yellow solid; */
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; */
    float: right;
  }

  .dogs-list img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .dogs-list h3 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

Looking forward!

Comment: Can you please show us the CSS for 'dogs-list', 'first-column', and 'dog'? It seems your issue may stem from a styling error.

Comment: @PhilipClark, I have pasted the styling area. But nothing works for it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to create two columns with left and right positioning instead of one area that produces the same result? For example, are you trying to make the left side a different color than the right, and thus the need for two separate column divs?

Comment: yes, the Blue UI must match the UI with the pink one along with the dynamic data. This is an assignment.

Comment: If by assignment, you mean a school-related assignment, please see [this article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for proper ways to get help on SO with such things.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a given structure to follow, (there was none mentioned?) try the following.

```
.dogs-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.dog{
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  background-color: beige;
  border: 2px yellow solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dogs-list img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dogs-list h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```
<div className='dogs-list'>
  {dog.map(data => (

    <div id={data.id} className='dog'>
      <img src={data.dogPic} alt='dog' />
      <h3> Dog 's Name</h3> <h3> {data.name} </h3>
    </div>

  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: You're right bro. I was trying the same approach. But the problem is with the dynamic data. I have loop single div, not over several numbers of divs. In the approach, you've shown, I can use loop and data can't be dynamic.

Comment: @SafarAli -- I have updated the answer to show more clearly how to implement a solution.

Comment: Hi There, Actually after a long time, I was successful. It was easy, just I needed to take a break. Due to consistently sitting in front of the computer, I got confused. Well, the answer is using inline instead of flex. And the problem is solved.